# Google cloud functions: Same storage trigger event is triggered over and over

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

**Problem**

Cloud function is triggered over and over again on the same event.
It looks like when the function times out, the function is retried
over and over? Although the option for "retry on failure" is not enabled in the gui?

**Question**

Can you guarantee that a function is only triggered once on the same event?
It could be related to these events in the issue tracker?:

- [High rates of duplicate messages in pubsub triggers](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/38448751)
- [Missing log entries](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38452949)

**More detail**

I have a cloud function which reacts on the upload of a file in a cloud storage bucket. The function converts an audio file into a flac file.

With a small file all works as expected. With a larger file things become really strange. The cloud function is triggered multiple times reacting on the same storage event over and over. I am confused how that could happen as I would think that if a function has reacted on the event, it will not be triggered anymore.

The deal is that when the function is triggered, that the function takes a while to execute its conversion. And it seems that in that that time, new functions are created to react on the event.

So is it possible to make sure that the cloud function is triggered only once?

This is the log file from the stackdriver

**Small file upload (all good)**

[image: Small file upload]

**Larger file (multiple invocations)**

[image: Larger file]

This shows that the function is triggered twice within a minute without the first invocation has finished yet?

Searching for that event I see its coming back over and over again:

[image: Event coming back over and over again.]

This is my code to react on the trigger:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const os = require("os");

const gcs = require("@google-cloud/storage")();
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
const ffmpeg_static = require("ffmpeg-static");

const speech = require("@google-cloud/speech")();
const Promise = require("bluebird");

//Helper function for changing the ffmpeg command into a promise so that the function will properly wait for it to finish.
//Source: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/710

function promisifyCommand(command) {
  return new Promise(cb => {
    command
      .on("end", () => {
        cb(null);
      })
      .on("error", error => {
        cb(error);
      })
      .run();
  });
}

exports.extractAudio = functions.storage
  .bucket("ulc-transcribe.appspot.com")
  .object()
  .onChange(event => {
    const object = event.data;
    const filePath = object.name;
    const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
    const fileBucket = object.bucket;
    const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
    const audioBucket = gcs.bucket("ucl-flac-audio");
    const metageneration = object.metageneration; // Number of times metadata has been generated. New objects have a value of 1.

    console.log("event: ", event);
    console.log("path: ", filePath + " name: " + fileName);

    // Exit if the file is not an upload
    if (!filePath.startsWith("ucl-uploads")) {
      console.log("Only uploads need to be converted");
      return true;
    }

    // Exit if the audio is already converted.
    if (fileName.endsWith("_output.flac")) {
      console.log("Already a converted audio.");
      return true;
    }

    // Exit if this is a move or deletion event.
    if (object.resourceState === "not_exists") {
      console.log("This is a deletion event.");
      return true;
    }

    //   // Exit if file exists but is not new and is only being triggered
    // // because of a metadata change.
    // if (resourceState === 'exists' && metageneration > 1) {
    //   console.log('This is a metadata change event.');
    //   return;
    // }

    const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
    const targetTempFileName =
      fileName.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + "_output.flac";
    const targetTempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), targetTempFileName);
    const targetStorageFilePath = path.join(targetTempFileName);

    console.log("downloading audio file...");
    console.log("Filename: " + fileName);
    console.log("tempFilePath", tempFilePath);

    // Step 1 - Start download
    return bucket
      .file(filePath)
      .download({
        destination: tempFilePath
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Audio downloaded locally to", tempFilePath);
        //Step 2 - Convert file
        console.log("Start conversion:");

        command = ffmpeg(tempFilePath)
          .setFfmpegPath(ffmpeg_static.path)
          .audioChannels(1)
          .audioFrequency(16000)
          .format("flac")
          .output(targetTempFilePath);

        command = promisifyCommand(command);
        return command
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Output audio created at", targetTempFilePath);
            console.log("Upload file");
            return audioBucket
              .upload(targetTempFilePath, {
                destination: targetStorageFilePath
              })
              .then(() => {
                console.log("Output audio uploaded to", targetStorageFilePath);
                // return bucket.upload("/tmp/output.flac", {
                //   destination: "ucl-flac-audio/test.flac"
                // });

                //Step 4 - Cleanup fs
                console.log("cleanup filesystem");
                fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
                fs.unlinkSync(targetTempFilePath);
              });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error ", +err);
          });
      });
  });
```

Comment: Are you saving the new file back to the same directory? If you are, that event is kicking off the same cloud function.

Comment: No it gets saved in a different bucket with a different name. (its just that looking at the event, its always the exact same event which is causing the function to trigger) its saved to the audiobucket  `const audioBucket = gcs.bucket("ucl-flac-audio"); return audioBucket
              .upload(targetTempFilePath, {
                destination: targetStorageFilePath
              })`

Comment: @Koen I have just created an issue for the same [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119160063). One year after you reported this, it's still current and GCF has since gone GA ;-( Is this still affecting you ?